# Http get post guru help fiddler

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, proxy, fiddler

I need help. I need log(safe full request) in iis 5(with headers etc) or look on it in proxy,fiddler etc
I use fiddler/ I have web config

Do you know HOW TO see ALL  REQUEST,request  from ALL PORTS and applications?
Can y recommend me proxy or http debugger?
I can not see request to my website in fiddler((((((

Maybe i need add propertyes in iis? I have tcp port in iis(default web site, and this site is default in root of wwwroot 
**TCP port 80? and proxy address 8888????????????? MAYBE**

> *Maybe i need change port of tcp to 8888?*
>   I add to web.comfig

In fiddler is option Monitor all connections i check it. I don't use filters

I have web site on my own machine and fiddler on it
GMAIL  send request on my site( get rss)
74.125.16.68 - W3SVC1 HOUSE 217.76.185.140 80 GET /24.rss - 200 1398 202 HTTP/1.1 217.76.185.140

I don't see this query in fiddler, but i see 
GET /mail/channel/bind?at=xn3j35onw91kr1q7zyzwjdx2653kr7&VER=6&it=548812&RID=rpc&SID=8787BE0499898773&CI=1&AID=78&TYPE=html&zx=bf28pr-v4mnm7&DOMAIN=mail.google.com&t=1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&

IN FIDDLEr i see
POST /mail/?ui=2&ik=ba4ed7ee39&view=cps&q=http%3A%2F%2F217.76.185.140%2F25.rss&cps=r&rt=j HTTP/1.1
answer
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8

while(1);

[[["v","NEGbCBCSn-c.en.","8","55f6abc2045673de",,]
,["di",749,"",""]
,["ub",[["^i",1240327921200]
,["^f",1240327921200]

CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have no experience with fiddler (although I hear it is cool).

Try wireshark: here: http://www.wireshark.org/

It is a network packet analyzer with filtering, so you could set the filters to capture the messages you want.